# CSRF issue with Microsoft Edge and IE11

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have a CSRF token issue that only occurs in MS Edge and IE11 - it works fine in Chrome, Firefox and even IE9.

The problem only occurs when doing Http post via Ajax. It gives me Http403 forbidden error.

I have followed the guide in Django here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/

Do I need to add some extra headers for IE11 / MS Edge? Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2):

2 hours later, and I found the answer myself...

To those who might have the same issue with Microsoft Edge and IE11, the fix lies with the setting CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN.

I tried setting it like this:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "subdomain.domain.com"
```

However, that did not work, even though it was a subdomain site. Setting it like this works like a charm:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".domain.com"
```